# send gridview as excel attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, email, gridview

i'm currently working on a project that has the following items:

- one gridview populated only by button click events
- several buttons that pass different queries to a database and display these results on the gridview mentioned above
- an export gridview to excel button
- and a send e-mail button that sends the gridview content in the e-mail body

my problem is that, instead of sending the gridview content in the e-mail body i want to send it as an attachment but i've spent about 3 hours on this and can't figure out how to do it. also if i have for example 6 query buttons, how do i make the "send e-mail" button send 6 different e-mails (the sequence should be, press query button and then press send-email button) with texts regarding the query has been passed?

some help would be appreciated

here's the relevant pieces of code

gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

query button

```
protected void ButtonQ1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct ITMREF_0 as COD_ART, CPNITMREF_0 as NOME_ART, CPNOPE_0 as TRANS_ART FROM [ERPDQ].[dbo].[DQBOMD] where CPNOPE_0 < 5 or CPNOPE_0 > 20", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

export to excel button

```
protected void Buttonexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=dados.xls");
        StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

send e-mail button

```
protected void Buttonmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@gmail.com");
            mm.Subject = "GridView Email";
            mm.Body = "GridView:<hr />" + sw.ToString(); ;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "sender@gmail.com";
            NetworkCred.Password = "***";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the excel file locally on the server after creating it, and then you'll be able to attach that file to the e-mail.

As to having the e-mail send based on whatever is clicked, you'll want separate the e-mail code out into its own method with some input parameters (to, from, body, file) and have the different buttons call that method with the appropriate values.

So let's say you create a button that generates an excel file called "export1".  After creating that file in the button click you'd call the SendEmail method and pass it the export1 file path as the file.  In the email method, you'd then attach that file to the email.

If that's not clear or doesn't set you on the right path, let me know and I'll set you up some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to save the HTML to a temporary file then use that as an attachment in each email. Here is code similar to what I use to generate temporary files:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".csv"
```

Then just pass the path for your Excel file around to the different function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I’m a c#/asp.net novice, but maybe if i explain the sequence of events (that makes sense to me at least) it will make things clearer:

- Press query button and display the results on the only gridview I
  have (and maybe save the file locally with a certain name that
  signals the file as the result of the query that has been passed)
- User can export the gridview to excel (this works perfectly) or send
  it as an excel file in an email attachment

After thinking about this for a while, is the only solution to my problem to have as many email buttons as I have query buttons and these email buttons read the gridview results and then transform them into an excel file? if so, how i accomplish this?

**EDIT :** i kinda got it, after the user presses the query button and the results are displayed, the email button sends those results as an excel attachment on an email, however after sending the email the app redirects me to a page that contains the gridview data from the query

**the results are displayed just fine**

the "normal" page

http://www7.pic-upload.de/19.11.13/dvg5wo9whuhq.png

and after pressing the email button, notice the gap between the 2 lines is now huge

http://www7.pic-upload.de/19.11.13/gtxmi7pshl5.png

the code for the page is a table (TR and TD) with all the data from the query (the code continues on with the div classes that are in the master page)

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_rightcontent_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">COD_ART</th><th scope="col">NOME_ART</th><th scope="col">TRANS_ART</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>numbers</td><td>numbers</td><td>numbers</td>
    </tr><tr>.........
```

```
</form>   


            </div>
        </div>
```

here's the email button code

```
protected void Buttonmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fn_AttachGrid();
}

public void fn_AttachGrid()
{

    StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);

    GridView1.RenderControl(hWriter);
    Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@domain.pt"));

    mail.Subject = "Sales Report";

    System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;

    byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(sWriter.ToString());

    System.IO.MemoryStream mAtt = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mBArray, false);

    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(mAtt, "dad.xls"));

    mail.Body = "Hi PFA";

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com", "name");

    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
    NetworkCred.UserName = "sender@gmail.com";
    NetworkCred.Password = "password";
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Send(mail);

    Label1.Text = "Email Sent";

}
```

**EDIT 2 :** i figured it out, the line "Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());" that i took from the export to excel button was causing the page to render the table again